# En AMP ¿Cómo muestro una lista que viene de un json, donde el nodo no tiene nombre?

Tags: javascript, html, email, amp

Estoy tratando de obtener valores de un json con Email AMP, pero para todos los valores que había necesitado hasta el momento no había problema, es hasta un nodo que solo me da una lista donde no sé cómo extraer los datos, **¿alguna idea?**

La lista de horas es lo que tendría que renderizar, pero la lista no incluye nombres, no se qué palabra clave podría servir para esos casos.

Este es parte del json que estoy trabajando y es en el nodo **slots** donde no sé como recuperarlo con Email AMP:

```
"appointmentAvailability": [
                {
                    "date": "2023-01-20",
                    "day": "Friday",
                    "restricted": false,
                    "slots": [
                        "10:00 am",
                        "10:15 am",
                        "11:00 am",
                        "11:15 am",
                        "11:30 am",
                        "11:45 am",
                        "12:00 pm",
                        "12:15 pm",
                        "12:30 pm",
                        "01:00 pm",
                        "02:15 pm",
                        "02:30 pm",
                        "03:00 pm",
                        "03:15 pm",
                        "03:30 pm",
                        "03:45 pm",
                        "04:00 pm",
                        "04:15 pm",
                        "04:30 pm",
                        "04:45 pm",
                        "05:00 pm",
                        "05:15 pm",
                        "05:30 pm",
                        "05:45 pm",
                        "06:00 pm",
                        "06:15 pm"
                    ],
                    "numberOfSlotsAvailable": 26,
                    "manufacturer": [
```

Esta es la forma en la que he estado consumiendo las listas y muestro el espacio donde debería de colocar esas horas:

```
<form method="post"
            action-xhr="https://api.example.com/"
            target="_top" on="submit-success:AMP.setState({ 'newVariable' : event.response})">
            <fieldset>
                Timeslots
                <br><br>
                <button type="submit">Search Locations</button>
            </fieldset>
            <div submit-success>
                <template type="amp-mustache">
                    Connection successful!
                    <ul>
                        {{#locations}}
                        <li>
                            <b>
                                {{name}}
                            </b>
                            <ul>
                                {{#appointmentAvailability}}
                                <li>
                                    <b>
                                        {{date}} Slots:
                                    </b>
                                    <ul>
                                        {{#slots}}
                                        <li>
                                            <b>
                                                {{aquí deberían de estar las horas}}
                                            </b>
                                        </li>
                                        {{/slots}}
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                {{/appointmentAvailability}}
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        {{/locations}}
                    </ul>
                </template>
            </div>
            <div submit-error>
                <template type="amp-mustache">
                    Connection failed!
                </template>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Gracias devs!

Answer (score 0):

ya estuve probando y encontré la solución que necesitaba, se necesita usar un punto {{.}} para referenciar esos elementos de una lista

y así queda mi código con la solución:

```
<div submit-success>
    <template type="amp-mustache">
        Connection successful!

        {{#locations}}
        <div>
            <b>{{name}}</b>
            {{#appointmentAvailability}}
            <div>
                <b>{{date}} Slots:</b>
                <div class="hours">
                    {{#slots}}
                    <div class="hour">{{.}}</div>
                    {{/slots}}
                </div>
            </div>
            {{/appointmentAvailability}}
        </div>
        {{/locations}}
    </template>
</div>
```